# Precession in the vector model of angular momentum - quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

The **vector model** of angular momentum in quantum mechanics says that, for example, the angular momentum vector $\mathbf{L}$ *precesses* about its projection on the $z$ axis, like this:

[image]

We can add $\mathbf{L}$ and $\mathbf{S}$ to make $\mathbf{J}$, so that $\mathbf{L}$ and $\mathbf{S}$ *precess* about $\mathbf{J}$, like this:

[image]

NOW:

1) Does the direction of precession (clockwise or anticlockwise) matter?

2) This is just a model, $\mathbf{L}$ and $\mathbf{S}$ do **not** actually precess, right?
So why do use this model?
Is it a way to take into account the fact that we don't know $L_x$ and $L_y$?

Comment: 1) the direction does matter (see [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vhump_5PsaoC&lpg=PA187&ots=DkCjYzt9JA&pg=PA187#v=onepage&q&f=false)). 2) $L$ and $S$ really do precess - it's something we can measure.

Comment: 2) The quantum mechanical operators for L and S do not precess, neither do the states, but their time dependent expectation values do. That's what the model tries to visualize. If you do one measurement, you will always end up with one of the eigenstates. Do the experiment an infinite number of times, average over the result and you will get a precessing vector. Instead of doing the experiment on one spin a large number of times, you can also do it in parallel with a large number of spins. That's what ESR, NMR and optical spin experiments do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My quantum mechanics teacher, always say to me, that those models for "see" the spin and the angular momentum, are not correct.

the reason is that the picture of an electron precessing associated with the spin in't correct because  the spin is'nt associated with any spacial coordinate. in quantum mechanics is better abandon those pictures, the important are the properties of L and S and the measure.